# Is it a good idea to have a category and its subcategories in the training set of an object segmentation model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision, image-segmentation, labeling

I hope you are doing great!

I am currently training an object segmentation model (detectron2 : mask rcnn)

The objective is to detect materials like **wood**, **plastic**, **glass** etc...

**wood** is one of the categories in my training set.

Is it a good idea to add other labels that are subcategories of **wood**? Like **table**, **desk** etc ... to my training set? and if so, how should I label them?

I tried adding **table**, I noticed that the model detects the table as an object **table** and then adds some small detections of **wood** on top of it. so when labeling the images, should I label the table as **table** and then label all its parts as **wood**? or should I just label the whole thing as **wood** and avoid adding subcategories to my dataset?

Thank you in advance, Have a good one.